# Unusual calling of destructor

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

I am having a strange problem instantiating a structure living inside a class, where in construction it calls the destructor (several times) and even calls the parent object destructor.

Class with structure:

```
class Model {

public:
     struct StepModelIO {
         StepModelIO(Model model, ...) {DoConstruction(Model model, ...);}

         StepModelIO(const StepModelIO &other) {DoConstruction(Model model, ...); }

         ~StepModelIO() {}

         DoConstruction() {
             ...
         }
    }
    Model(...) {
       ...
    }

    Model(const Model &other) {DoConstruction(...);}

    ~Model() {
        ...
    }
private:
    DoConstruction(...) {

    }

}
```

Calling function:

```
void main() {

    Model::StepModelIO stepArgs = Model::StepModelIO(...);

}
```

The resulting set of calls, with 'object' being the `StepModelIO` and 'parent' being the `Model`:

1. Construct parent w/ copy constructor
2. Construct object
3. Destruct parent
4. Construct object w/ copy constructor
5. Construct parent w/ copy constructor
6. Construct object
7. Destruct parent
8. Destruct object
9. Destruct object (again...)
10. Destruct parent

Unsurprisingly the resulting structure (a `StepModelIO`) is not in a good state after this all happens, and the path seemed ridiculous. I have the structure housed like this to use the same generic at the parent Model object, which may explain some of the issues.

I have tried (perhaps naively) to use the 'rule of three' on constructors and destructors, it's possible I've munged this up badly.

**Edit:** Full code

```
template<typename U, typename V>
class Model{

public:

    struct StepModelIO {
        Model<U, V> model;
        U u;
        V v;

        StepModelIO() {}

        StepModelIO(Model<U, V> model, U u, V v) {
            this->model = model;
            this->u = u;
            this->v = v;
        }

        StepModelIO (const StepModelIO &other) {
            StepModelIO(other.model, other.u, other.v);
        }

        ~StepModelIO() {
        }
    };

    Model(char * libraryPath) {DoConstruction(libraryPath);}

    Model() {}

    Model (const Model &other) {
        DoConstruction(other.m_LibraryPath);
    }

    ~Model() {
        this->Stop();
    }

    void Init() {
        if (!this->m_Initialised) {
            this->ModelInit();
            m_Initialised = true;
        }
    }

    void Stop() {
        if (this->m_Initialised) {
            this->ModelStop();
            m_Initialised = false;
        }       
    }

    void Restart() {
        this->ModelRestart();
    }

    void Step(U u, V v) {
        ModelStep(u, v);
    }

private:

    char* m_LibraryPath;
    HINSTANCE m_ModelDLL;

    bool m_Initialised;

    typedef int (__cdecl * EmptyModelFunctionPointer)(); // Interpret integer as C code pointer named 'EmptyModelFunctionPointer'
    typedef int (__cdecl * ModelFunctionPointer)(U u, V v);

    EmptyModelFunctionPointer ModelInit;
    EmptyModelFunctionPointer ModelStop;
    EmptyModelFunctionPointer ModelRestart;
    ModelFunctionPointer ModelStep;

    virtual void DoConstruction(char * libraryPath){
        this->m_Initialised = false;
        this->m_LibraryPath = libraryPath;
        this->m_ModelDLL = LoadLibrary(libraryPath);
        this->ModelInit = GetFunction<EmptyModelFunctionPointer>(m_ModelDLL, "Init");   
        this->ModelStop = GetFunction<EmptyModelFunctionPointer>(m_ModelDLL, "Stop");
        this->ModelRestart = GetFunction<EmptyModelFunctionPointer>(m_ModelDLL, "Restart");
        this->ModelStep = GetFunction<ModelFunctionPointer>(m_ModelDLL, "Step");
    }

    template<typename pointerType>
    pointerType GetFunction(HINSTANCE modelLibrary, char * functionName){
        return (pointerType)GetProcAddress(HMODULE (modelLibrary),functionName);
    }
};
```

Caller:

```
StepModelIO<Type_1*, Type_2*> stepArgs = StepModelIO<Type_1*, Type_2*>(newModel, &a, &b[0]);
```

Comment: Did you check with a debugger? Sounds like you may corrupt the stack in your initalisation, but since you posted no real code, this is just guessing from the crystal ball.

Comment: The declaration you show in the `main` function does *not* create an instance of the "parent" class. If it does, then you're doing something you're not showing us. Please make a [short and self contained example](http://sscce.org/) showing the problem.

Comment: Code you posted does not show any problem. Are there any temporary local object instances inside constructors? Are there member pointers?

Comment: Post the real code with real parameters used

Comment: Code added per request. @Joachim Pileborg the sequence of operations I listed above comes from the debugger. Part of the question is understanding how this one seemingly innocuous constructor call manages to touch so much code that it shouldn't be.

Comment: The code you provided seems ok at the first look. Can you please provide us with a use case of Model<>::StepModelIO  ?

Comment: All those `...` and the `void main` are not valid C++. Please show us your _real_ [testcase](http://sscce.org); the one you've been debugging on for the past few days. Note: a testcase is not your "full code", but a _different_ program with a similar structure and no irrelevant code, that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing things by value,  which will result in temporary objects being constructed and destructed. Pass them by const reference instead.

change

```
  StepModelIO(Model model, ...)
```

to

```
  StepModelIO(const Model &model, ...)
```

---

You've now changed the code. So you really want this, I think.

```
 StepModelIO(const Model<U, V> &model, const U &u, const V &v)
```

Comment: Hi @Roddy thanks for the help, yep I wasn't sure if the generics were going to be a part of the problem or no, tried to simplify it. I think your first sentence might be a start towards my understanding the problem. You're suggesting passing objects by value implicitly calls constructors/destructors/copies etc. Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: @JCollins - Here's a good place to start. http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/

Comment: Thanks @Roddy I had no idea unmanaged languages behaved this way. I have seen a similar thing with .net properties with ByRef vs ByVal passing of arguments, but I figured in the unmanaged world I was responsible for everything quite manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have notices tat inside the class `StepModelIO` you have a member `Model<U, V> model;` so for each instance of class `StepModelIO` the destructor of model will be caled also; first `~StepModelIO()` and second `~Model<U, V>()`

so given the code you provided:

```
Model::StepModelIO stepArgs = Model::StepModelIO(...);
```

This has two objects of the type `StepModelIO`. One is the on in the right (rvalue) and the second one is `stepArgs`.

First the destructor for the one in the right is called resulting in:

1:`Destruct StepModelIO`

2:`Destruct Model`

And when the destruction of stepArgs occurs :

3:`Destruct StepModelIO`

4:`Destruct Model`